# Looping through DataGridView Search Row and Columns

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, datagridview, desktop-application, desktop

Having DataGrind In Windows application Enable search option like Microsoft Excel search entire sheet (DataGrid).

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DisplayGridView.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value == searchValue)
                {
                    cell.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
       }
```

I have tried above method but not getting result. I have impliment this code

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DisplayGridView.Rows)
        {               
            for (int i = 0; i < DisplayGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (row.Cells[i].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                {
                    row.Cells[i].Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Still, the result is null can anyone suggest the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not checking for null values. Adding these null value checks appears to work as you describe. Adding the `ToString()` method to the line : `cell.Value == searchValue` after `Value` makes the comparison successful. Also the breaks are not needed.

```
DisplayGridView.ClearSelection();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DisplayGridView.Rows) {
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
    if (cell.Value != null) {
      if (cell.Value.ToString() == searchValue) {
        cell.Selected = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next method

```
DisplayGridView.ClearSelection();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DisplayGridView.Rows) {
  for (int i = 0; i < DisplayGridView.Columns.Count; i++) {
    if (row.Cells[i].Value != null) {
      if (row.Cells[i].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue)) {
        row.Cells[i].Selected = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to highlight the cell if the search string is contained in the cells string, then you only need to change the equals method to contains.

```
DisplayGridView.ClearSelection();
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DisplayGridView.Rows) {
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
      if (cell.Value != null) {
        if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue)) {
          cell.Selected = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code i posted works when I ran it. What error are you getting?

Comment: Not getting any error just my cursor move on first row first column no result fetch

Comment: Then you should debug it. Put a message box where the search value matches and the cell gets set to selected. If you see the message box and the cell is not selected, then something is going on after this. If you never see the message box, then the search string was not found.

Comment: See If my search code is Fashions and the cell value is "ASHA PRIYA FASHIONS" then it will search the value or not ?

Comment: Hmm.. Are you asking if the strings are equal or if the search string is contained in a string... Those are two different things.

Comment: It's finding the exact value and the cursor is not moving to matched cell. It's getting select bur cursor position not moving.

Comment: That was not part of the question, but simply set the cursor when you set the selection. However, if there is more than ONE cell selected, I am not sure WHICH cell you would want to place the cursor. And if you did set the cursor into one of the selected cells, the searched selection would be removed as soon as you set this cursor.

Comment: I know that is not a part of the question but it required to complete the question. I'm removing the last selection to set new Selection DisplayGridView.ClearSelection(); but the new selection is not getting focused

Comment: If there are multiple cells selected, they all have focus. If you click on another cell, they all lose focus. As soon a you give a cell "Focus" or set the cursor into a cell... all other selected cells will lose focus. Do you want to "Select" these search cells or color them.

Comment: WOW… I thought your infantile comment: _”I know that is not a part of the question but it required to complete the question.”_...  was a joke! Guess I was wrong. Good Luck.

Comment: Appreciate your reply bu the code is not working it's only giving result for proper name suppose I'm searching sunil and the data has "SUNIL ACHARYA" result is blank.